# how to remove NA columns from TDM for clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, term-document-matrix

I'm struggling with TDM NA values to commit the clustering. Initially I've set:

```
titles.tdm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(titles.cw, control = list(bounds = list(global = c(10,Inf)))))

titles.sc <- scale(na.omit(titles.tdm))
```

and got matrix of 418 terms and 6955 documents. At this point executing:
`titles.km <- kmeans(titles.sc, 2)` throws
`Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)`

When I've decided to remove those values by:

`titles.sf <- titles.sc[,colSums(titles.sc) > 0]`

I've got matrix of 4695 documents, but applying the `kmeans` function still throws this error. When I've viewed the `titles.sf` variable there are still columns (docs) with NA values. I'm messed up and don't know what doing wrong. How to remove those documents?

Earlier, I've applied `titles.cw <- titles.cc[which(str_trim(titles.cc$content) != "")]` where `titles.cc` is pure Corpus object from `tm` library class, to delete black documents. It probably worked, but my NA values are in documents which are not blank for sure.

Comment: There shouldn't be any NA values in a correct TDM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
titles.sc <- matrix(1:25,5,5)
titles.sc[sample(length(titles.sc),5)]<-NA 
titles.sc
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
# [2,]    2    7   12   17   NA
# [3,]    3   NA   13   18   23
# [4,]    4    9   14   NA   24
# [5,]    5   NA   15   NA   25
```

`kmeans` throws your error

```
kmeans(titles.sc, 2)
# Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

because your column subsetting is probably not what you'd expect:

```
colSums(titles.sc) > 0
# [1] TRUE   NA TRUE   NA   NA
```

`colSums` produces `NA`, if missing values are not removed (check the help files under `?colSums`). Among other things, you could do

```
colSums(is.na(titles.sc)) == 0
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

or

```
!is.na(colSums(titles.sc) > 0)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

And now, it works:

```
titles.sf <- titles.sc[,colSums(is.na(titles.sc)) == 0,drop=F]
kmeans(titles.sf,2)
# K-means clustering with 2 clusters of sizes 2, 3
# ...
```